# How to set limitation because of some number in regex?

Tags: regex

I want to make a regular expression that direct the time format is valid, the format should like this:
HH:MM

so, I create a regular expression like this:

```
/\b[0-2][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]\b/
```

But the problems occur, the user still can input something like 29:59. Which is not a valid time. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex `OR` for the hour:

```
/\b([01][0-9]|2[0-3])\:[0-5][0-9]\b/
```

The `([01][0-9]|2[0-3])` part is saying hours can be anything 00-19 *or* 2 with (0-3).
A regex `OR` takes the form of `(A|B)`